# KeyError: None of [Index([(....)])] are in the columns for a list of columns generated with df.columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df_a` that contains all columns. Then I have `df_b` that contains a subset of this dataframe. I want to select the columns that are in `df_b` from `df_a`.

Why does the following code not work?

```
df_a[[df_b.columns]]
```

It throws a KeyError `"None of [Index([(....), (....))], dtype='object)] are in the [columns]`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner `[]` is redundant, you can try

```py
df_a[df_b.columns]
# or
df_a.reindex(columns=df_b.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I often use the inner `[]` for keeping something as a dataframe instead of it becoming a series.  `df['a']` will return a series while `df[['a']]` will still be of type dataframe. Are there any better alternatives for this?

Comment: @RogerKint That's two things, you can understand the result of `df.columns` as it always returns a list so you needn't wrap it into another list.

Comment: Aah that makes sense, so that is also why if the columns in `df_b` are `Name` and `Age` and I use `df_a['Name', 'Age']` it will throw a `KeyError` but if I do `df_a[['Name', 'Age']] it does work, right?

Comment: @RogerKint Not quietly, syntax of `df[]` is used to select columns. You can use `df['Name']` to select single column `Name` or use `df[['Name', 'Age']]` to select a list of columns `Name` and `Age`. Syntax like `df['Name', 'Age']` is used to select multiIndex columns.